# EXT JS 4 Create dynamic grid, columns decided at runtime

Tags: ajax, json, extjs4

I am using EXTJS4. I have a tree which displays classes (classname) on one side. On clicking the class names,  I want to be able to display the objects belonging to that class in a separate Grid. The objects will be fetched from the server using ajax and json format.
The problem is each class has different number of attributes(columns) so I cannot decide the columns statically.
How can I create the grid columns dynamically for each class ? The number of columns will first need to be got from the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely no problem. You don't have to specify everything in the code. ExtJs 4.0 grid has a method `reconfigure` which you can use to change store/columns for existing grid. Take a look here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure

Comment: Taking this question further, do I need to make 2 separate ajax requests, first to get the column names" and the second one to get the actual data ? I am doing this, the column headers are being displayed , but the data is not visible in the grid. I know that the data is being fetched because the grid shows empty stripe rows...any ideas ?

Comment: Load is asynchronous call. You need to do first Ajax call and after it finishes, adjust grid columns and only then do the load.

Comment: Great ! worked now...I didnt realise that the ajax call needs to be finished first. The grid is now displaying data. Thanks again.